# TexStudio Shortcut Editing

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

It's not really a shortcut edit as I know how to do so.

On TexStudio, when I type for example `\begin{figure}` and select one of the options in popup toolbar, it gives me `\label{}` and `\end{figure}` and so on. But I want to edit what I can get out of this when I enter one of the options in popup toolbar.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Cheers,
P

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you really want:

**Simpy add addtional tex directives to the completer**

This is achieved using cwl files. See [FAQ: What are cwl files good for and how do they work?](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#what-are-cwl-files-good-for-and-how-do-they-work).

**Generate arbitrary pieces of code by completion**

Use `Macros -> User Macros` with Abbreviation.

[image]

The Abbreviation will show up in the completer with the addition "(Usertag)" to distinguish it from regular commands.

[image]

You can also use abbreviations without leading backslash. In that case, the completer will not open automatically. You'll have to manually start it by `Ctrl+Space` (`Cmd+Space` on OSX).